# How to post form to my server and then to API, instead of posting directly(for security reasons)?

Tags: web-applications, forms-authentication, security

There is an integration with an API for conducting live online classes. The API wanted us to  post a form to their site along with a parameter called `customer_token` as an input field. It is used for authentication by the API and every customer site is assigned one token. The customer token is actually some hashed value of the domain name or IP or something.

Now, after the integration, they want me to hide the `customer_token` input field somehow from being accessible through mozilla's firebug and similar tools, because anybody can see the token and send a similar form to the API and access the API's service. Needless to say, the API is not developed by some experts. They did not realize the issue before and it is not a widely used API.

I asked a question previously on [Best way to hide a form input field from being accessed using firebug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510011/best-way-to-hide-a-form-input-field-from-being-accessed-using-firebug) and realised that it is not possible to hide any information through a get/post method. Someone asked me about whether the request is directly being sent to the api, or first to my server or something?

Please explain how does it fix the security issue and how do I implement it?

Thanks,
Sandeepan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could POST to your server, which in a script, POSTs all the parameters to the API form action, but with the `customer_token` added in your script, server-side, which clients can't see.

So, you have your original form:

```
<form action="http://someapi.com/blah" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="customer_token" value="foo">
    <input type="text" name="whatever">
    ...
</form>
```

And instead use:

```
<form action="myapiblah.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="whatever">
    ...
</form>
```

Note that there's no `customer_token` in the second example. Then, in `myapiblah.php` - change the name obviously, especially depending on the server-side language you're using. I might be able to provide more specific examples if you tell me what you use - use something like this psuedo-code:

```
parameters = $_POST;
parameters['customer_token'] = 'foo';
send_http_request('POST', 'http://someapi.com/blah', parameters);
```

You'll need to look up the details of what to use for `send_http_request`.

In PHP, you'd do something like this, if you can use the `pecl_http` stuff in PECL:

```
$params = $_POST;
$params['customer_token'] = 'foo';

$req = new HttpRequest('http://someapi.com/blah', HttpRequest::METH_POST);
$req->addQueryData($params);
try {
    $r->send();
    if ($r->getResponseCode() == 200) {
        // success!
    }
    else {
        // got to the API, the API returned perhaps a RESTful response code like 404
    }
}
catch (HttpException $ex) {
    // couldn't get to the API (probably)
}
```

Comment: thats what I was looking for.. I didnt know about the send_http_request function. And yes I work on PHP too. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @sandeepan: There isn't actually a `send_http_request` function - I was merely using that in psuedocode. :) You should, however, be able to build on the PHP at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

the you asked you is right! does the form goes first to the webserver? this means is the site posted to a normal url for which apache or onother webserver takes the request or does the form goes to a specific services (like a webserver, which is also only a services which listens on a port - port 80 for webservers, mostly). if you hide a field in a webform, it is useless. if you take a look at the source code of the site you still can see the hidden field.!!